# Don't get prompt to save- CRM Solution export

Tags: export, crm, prompt

While exporting a Solution from CRM, I dont get the prompt to save the exported solution.
I cleared Cookies and tried,
Upgraded to IE 9 also and tried,
I made sure that the Popup is not blocked, but these things didn't help.
This is the case with few other colleagues of mine also.\

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I usually get a popup right at the bottom of the window. Its not instant however, Crm has to generate the solution file, so if its particulary large it can take a minute or two. I would suggest clicking export, finish the dialog and then waiting 5 minutes to see if anything happens (it needs a loading icon really).

If that doesnt work, try the same again with a small solution (one entity).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know it is too late but I am adding the solution here if someone faces the issue again.

The issue was due to URLScan. It was solved by removing URLScan from ISAPI filters for CRM web site.